# Can't click on email verification button with python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm beginner in python and I'm trying to learn on how to use selenium by creating an account in protonmail. Everything seems to be going fine but I am unable to click on the email radio button after I've clicked on "create account". Any help would be great! Thank you!

[4 radio buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqbAz.png)

Here's a part of the code that I'm trying to fix which is used to click onto the radio button.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"iframe.input[type='radio'][value='email']")))

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='id-signup-radio-email']"))).click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest just using the button id to click it as well as just using `presence_of_element_located` like so:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "id-signup-radio-email"))).click()
```

Alternatively you can also first wait for the element presence and use JavaScript to click it like so:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "id-signup-radio-email")))
driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("id-signup-radio-email").click()')
```

The JS option is sometimes better in terms of not getting "element is not clickable" or "element is not attached to the page" errors.

Answer (score 0):

I cound't open your hyperlink above, so don't know the issure excatly.As far as I know, radio buttons always binded with description text elements who always be it's parent or brothers.
For UI elements, default response chain would forward by UI lay-out.A user action will be forward by UI layers, front layer would forward to back layer UI if it 't not listen to the action.
But we often come across scenario radio element(input & div tag) not response to click action, due to action achain forward to radio's parent or brother element who listen to and response for this action.

@Suuny909 **try click radio(input&div)'s parent or brother element**, that might work?